# Documentation for bin/nutch elasticindex

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch, nutch

There is a lot of documentation and examples using the `bin/nutch solrindex` command, but the `bin/nutch elasticindex` command is lacking in coverage. I am struggling to combine an instance of Nutch 2.2.1 with Elasticsearch 0.90.2. I've tried to use [this plugin](https://github.com/marevol/elasticsearch-mocksolrplugin/tree/develop) to disguise Elasticsearch as a Solr instance, but any `bin/crawl` jobs crash from internal server error. What I am looking for is an example of `bin/crawl` modified to use Elasticsearch or a detailed description of the `bin/nutch elasticindex` command (the nutch wiki doesn't have a page for it). Can I simply replace every occurrence of the phrase `solrindex` with `elasticindex` freely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified `bin/crawl` to remove the `bin/nutch solrdedup` command, and replaced all mentions of `solrindex` with `elasticindex`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make Nutch 2.2.x work with Elasticsearch. But I don't see the added benefit of 2.2.x compared with 1.8. The only thing is that Nutch 2.2.x uses Gora to save the crawled pages in a database of your choice. Since you are using Elasticsearch to index the results I assume you don't need the database.
I made Nutch 1.8 with Elasticsearch 0.90.11 and you can find the bundle on my GitHub account:
https://github.com/andreivisan/NutchElasticsearch